# error proxying from react app to express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, backend

I'm trying to use an express server with a react.js app and I faced an error in proxying.
this is the error:
[HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/api to http://localhost:3001/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

proxysetup.js:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3001/',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";

import "./App.css";
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.message));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
  
        <p>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello from express!" });
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

[files path:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GO5s.png)

Comment: Where did you use the `proxysetup`? I didn't see it

Comment: check files path i added it now

Comment: OK, I am aware of you are using [Configuring the Proxy Manually](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually) of CRA.

Comment: not the same author but the same solution yes